# How to compute the following double sum $\sum_{z_1,z_2 \in [-N,..N]: z_1 \neq z_2} z_1^2-2z_1z_2$

Tags: summation

How to compute the following double summation 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{z_1,z_2 \in [-N,..N]: z_1 \neq z_2}  z_1^2-2z_1z_2
\end{align*}

I was thinking I can do the following 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{z_1,z_2 \in [-N,..N]: z_1 \neq z_2}  z_1^2-2z_1z_2=\sum_{z_1,z_2 \in [-N,..N]: z_1 \neq z_2}  (z_1-z_2)^2-z_2^2
\end{align*}
But next I get lost in indices.
Can some one show a nice and systematic solution

Comment: $$\sum_{z_1 \neq z_2} (z_1^2 - 2 z_1z_2) = \sum (z_1^2 - 2z_1z_2) + \sum_{-N}^N z_1^2.$$ I think that makes dealing with the indices easier.

Comment: Maybe getting rid of the $z_1≠z_2$ condition by subtracting all those terms would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\sum_{z_1 \neq z_2} \,z_1z_2=\sum_{z_1,z_2}\,z_1z_2-\sum_{z_1}\,z_1^2=\left(\sum_{z_1}\,z_1\right)\left(\sum_{z_2}\,z_2\right)-\sum_{z_1}\,z_1^2$ and $\sum_{z_1 \neq z_2}\,z_1^2 = 2N\,\sum_{z_1}\,z_1^2$.

After some algebraic manipulation, the answer should be $$(2N+2)\cdot 2\left(\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}\right)=\frac{2N(N+1)^2(2N+1)}{3}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks. I have a question the su $\sum_{z-1 \in [-N...N],z_2 \in [-N...N]} z_1z_2 =0$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}S_N=\!\!\!\sum_{\substack{-N\leq z_1,z_2\leq N\\ z_1\neq z_2}}\!\!(z_1^2-2z_1 z_2)&=&\sum_{-N\leq z_1,z_2\leq N}(z_1^2-2z_1 z_2)+\sum_{-N\leq z\leq N}z^2\\&=&(2N+2)\sum_{-N\leq z\leq N}z^2-2\,\left(\sum_{-N\leq z\leq N}z\right)^2\\&=&(4N+4)\sum_{n=1}^{N}n^2\\&=&\frac{2}{3}N(N+1)^2(2N+1).\end{eqnarray*}$$